# Is it possible to open a popup/alert box in ESXi's DCUI to alert users?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have built a zero-touch kickstart image of ESXi 6.7 for deployment of several hundred servers in a remote warehouse.  I would like to get a popup or alert type box to display on the DCUI screen so the the deployers understand that the deployment is done and so I can display some information to help with quality control.  I believe I have seen something like this in the past and know it has to be possible, but have not found anything on it yet.

EDIT: I would like to try to do it similarly to the way ESXi says when the host is installed (below), but I want to be able to run it from a script at will.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either change the contents of the file /etc/vmware/welcome manually, or you can do it with

```
esxcli system welcomemsg set -m="your message"
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea - I am hoping to not make a permanent change the the message, but rather have the kickstart script open a dialog box one time (much like the installation complete dialog box, just with custom values on firstboot)